# How can I convince people I actually like my job and don't think its beneath me?

Tags: software-development, colleagues

I recently joined a software development team to test out the applications they develop. I like development, but I genuinely enjoy testing, and to be perfectly honest I don't like their development environment, so I have zero interest in digging into it. (Should note that I'm new to the team, not the organization, so I've known and worked with these folks a lot.)

Most everybody seems fine with this...but there is one person who is baffled I don't want to join in on the development. He has multiple times tried to bolster my confidence by basically saying I am totally qualified to develop, and I shouldn't have to take on work beneath me since that's the boring stuff. (Sorry I'm paraphrasing a few weeks worth of conversation.)

While I appreciate his confidence, I know I'm qualified, and as I mentioned before, I like this work. In my opinion, good testing is just a different kind of problem-solving (not "beneath me"), and not a lot of developers want to do it (like this guy; hence his confusion).

This isn't the worst problem in the world to have, but it got me wondering: is there a way to convince somebody I like my job, even when they think it's a terrible job?

Comment: "different strokes for different folks". Tell him that you are not him

Comment: I actually like both(but hate system-related tasks), and can perfectly understand you.  We all have different tastes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From my experience (different field but manager tried to convince me to join his team):

> I know I'm qualified to do that, that's why you want me to join. The thing is that I'm not only good in doing X I'm also great in doing Y and to be frank Y give me much more enjoyment in doing it. And that enjoyment is something that can't be turned into money.

Don't try to explain why X is as good as Y or why it's not so bad (because that can be argued with), just say what's your personal preference (because you can't argue with that).

Answer (score 4):

Your colleague has, most likely, a shallow understanding of what testing is and how it can help his team. Show him this guy's page: http://www.satisfice.com/blog/ He may understand that testing is a bit more than he thought. Maybe he will become a tester himself.

Answer (score 3):

> Hey buddy, thanks for your encouragement, but I know I'm qualified already. I like my testing job because X, Y, and Z, and I don't think it's beneath me. I'm not interested in pursuing a development role at the moment, thanks for the vote of confidence though, I appreciate it!

Or something to that effect. It's doesn't need to be more complicated than that :-)

Comment: While I think your answer should 100% be the right and is probably right for others, it didn't work for me (hence the few weeks back and forth). Still, please take the upvote. :)

Answer (score 2):

Any competent developer in a corporate environment would realize that Testing is a completely different skillset, and has challenges, opportunities and a career path that is totally different from development. If this developer doesn't realize that, I'd refer him to the previous sentence and ask him to look up the word 'competent'.

Answer (score 1):

'I like testing'... rinse and repeat.

Comment: without an explanation, this answer may become useless in case if someone else posts an opposite opinion. For example, if someone posts a claim like _"Don't just say 'I like testing'"_, how would this answer help reader to pick of two opposing opinions? Consider [edit]ing it into a better shape, to meet [answer] guidelines